# How to enumerate arbitrary nd-array with write enabled in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to fill arbitrary array with increasing integers, but failed:

```
import numpy as np

sz = 3
sh = (30, 10, 10, 3)

xs = []
for i in range(sz):
    xs.append(np.zeros(sh))

value = 0

for i in range(sz):
    for index, value in np.ndenumerate(xs[i]):
        xs[i][list(index)] = value
        value += 1
```

After the following code, all arrays in `xs` list remains zero. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your counter and loop variable are the same: `value`.

```
for index, _ in np.ndenumerate(xs[i]):
    xs[i][list(index)] = value
    value += 1
```

`value` takes on 0 every time the loop iterates, resetting the actual count value. Hide it with an underscore, I don't believe you need it.

Alternatively, you could use `np.arange` and just reshape:

```
xs = np.arange(sz * np.prod(sh))
```